# Inequality in four variables which sum up to 4

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

The positive real numbers $x,y,z,t$ satisfy $x+y+z+t=4$.
Is the inequality $$x\sqrt{y}+y\sqrt{z}+z\sqrt{t}+t\sqrt{x}\leq4$$ true for all $x,y,z,t>0$?

Comment: The key lies in proving that the LHS of the second inequality has its maximum at $x = y = z = t = 1$ (under the given constraints)

Comment: @Just_a_fool Unless you want to get into Lagrange multipliers, you'll rarely see that approach work directly with inequalities like these. Seing as this is tagged with _precalculus_, I'm assuming the OP doesn't have that kind of machinery available.

Comment: I have, but I don't want to "attack" this nice inequality with calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$x+xy\ge 2x\sqrt y,\cdots$$
we only need to show
$$xy+yz+zt+tx\le 4.$$
Equivalently we need
$$\tag{1}(x+z)(y+t)\le 4.$$
Let $x+z=u$, then $y+t=4-u$ and (1) becomes the obvious
$$u(4-u)\le 4.$$

Comment: Ah! AM-GM inequality. +1